# can we remove wait using while loop with anything else for global variable of thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

[image: Explanation of problem]

In below code, i am trying to calculate the value of x1 and x2 sequentially using thread.. (In real case, x1 and x2 will be big calculations)
but waiting for both thread to calculate the value of respective variables using while loop is becoming costly for the processor.
Issue is, i want both threads to run parallel, but loop of both threads should be equally serialized (means should run once in one calling).
Hence, is there any way to remove these while loops and get the result serially. I am very confused for using semaphores and mutex, as x1 and x2 are independent 
of each other? Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t pth1,pth2;
//Values to calculate
int x1 = 0, x2 = 0;
//Values for condition
int cond1 = 0,cond2 = 0;


void *threadfunc1(void *parm)
{
    for (;;) {
        // Is this while loop is very costly for the processor?
        while(!cond1) {}
        x1++;
        cond1 = 0;
    }
    return NULL ;
}
void *threadfunc2(void *parm)
{
    for (;;) {
        // Is this while loop is very costly for the processor?
        while(!cond2) {}
        x2++;
        cond2 = 0;
    }
    return NULL ;
}



int main () {
    pthread_create(&pth1, NULL, threadfunc1, "foo");
    pthread_create(&pth2, NULL, threadfunc2, "foo");
    int loop = 0;
    while (loop < 10) {
        // iterated as a step
        loop++;
        printf("Initial : x1 = %d, x2 = %d\n", x1, x2);
        cond1 = 1;
        cond2 = 1;
        // Is this while loop is very costly for the processor?
        while(cond1) {}
        while(cond2) {}
        printf("Final   : x1 = %d, x2 = %d\n", x1, x2);
    }

    pthread_cancel(pth1);
    pthread_cancel(pth2);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Parallel or serial? What do you want?

Comment: The `condX` variables need to be protected against concurrent access.

Comment: You may want to try `pthread_cond_wait` http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait

Comment: @Rohan: This and more had been shown to the OP in answers to one of his/her last question.

Comment: x1 and x2 should be calculated parallel, but after single calculation next calculation of x1 and x2 should be invoked.

Comment: Why do you want to have the threads run synchronised this way? You want to have thread1/thread2 wait until thread2/thread1 had done one iteration before running the next iteration?

Comment: to perform step solve in a solver.. each step should be divided into group of calculation which will be calculated in parallel, but each iteration should be sequential..

Comment: to calculate x1, x2, x3, .... xn values
group x1,..,x5 and x6,...,x10 and x11,...,x15 and xn-5,...xn groups are formed..
threads are invoked for calulation of each group.
each group will be calculated for single iteration and data is passed to other array for further big calculations
after next x values are calculated (which may have changed because of further big calculations) in parallel way. Hope i am able to explain myself

Comment: i am struggling with some serious time issues, my code is running very slow, hence asking again and again... @alk

Comment: An easy way out will be to avoid infinite loop in worker threads and instead, `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` worker threads each time you want. :)

Comment: @rajraj but i cannot exit the thread until 10 iterations

Comment: Because of using local data inside the scope of those threads?

Comment: may be you are suggesting to create and recreate the thread every time i need.. I tried that way.,, but recreating thread it costing me more time @rajraj

Comment: @alk please check: to calculate x1, x2, x3, .... xn values group x1,..,x5 and x6,...,x10 and x11,...,x15 and xn-5,...xn groups are formed.. threads are invoked for calulation of each group. each group will be calculated for single iteration and data is passed to other array for further big calculations after next x values are calculated (which may have changed because of further big calculations) in parallel way. Hope i am able to explain myself

Comment: Then the way is to use synchronization objects like mutexes. In the worker thread, inside infinite loop, do `pthread_mutex_lock` and after calculation, `pthread_mutex_unlock` that mutex. In main thread, inside the loop, first unlock the mutex and then wait for that mutex using `pthread_mutex_lock`. Thats all. Need one mutex for each thread.

Comment: But @rajraj is loop will wait till i lock the thread? and when i am printing final result in the code. i need to add more calculation using x1 and x2... hence needs to wait both thread there.. will it be helpful?

Comment: Hi @alk i had added an image to explain my problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the while loops in threadfunc1 and threadfunc2, then the threads would return and not proceed. So, you most certainly need a way for the thread to remain alive till it completes its computation of the series (10, in this case).

Here is a sample code that shows trying to co-ordinate between the main thread and the two threads. With the pthread_cond_wait(), the wait moves from a simple "while" loop to the pthread_cond_wait().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//Values to calculate
int x1 = 0, x2 = 0;
//Values for condition
int cond1 = 0, cond2 = 0;

static pthread_mutex_t m1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t m2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t c = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *threadfunc1(void *parm) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        printf("\t\tThread1 with x1 = %d\n", x1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
        if (cond1 == 0) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m1);
        }
        x1++;
        cond1 = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\t\tThread1 returns with x1 = %d\n", x1);
    return NULL ;
}

void *threadfunc2(void *parm) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        printf("\t\tThread2 with x2 = %d\n", x2);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);
        if (cond2 == 0) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m2);
        }
        x2++;
        cond2 = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\t\tThread2 returns with x2 = %d\n", x2);
    return NULL ;
}


int main () {
    pthread_t pth1, pth2;
    pthread_create(&pth1, NULL, threadfunc1, "foo");
    pthread_create(&pth2, NULL, threadfunc2, "foo");
    int retVal;
    int loop = 0;
    while (loop <= 10) {
        loop++;
        cond1 = 1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&c);

        cond2 = 1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&c);
        printf("Loop [%d]: x1 = %d, x2 = %d\n", loop, x1, x2);
    }

    retVal = pthread_join(pth1, NULL);
    retVal = pthread_join(pth2, NULL);
    printf("Final : x1 = %d, x2 = %d\n", x1, x2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But, when i am printing final, i actually need to pass the data (x1 and x2) for other calculations and after this only i can move for next iterations..

Comment: In that case, we should use pthread_cond_wait for the main thread to signal each thread, one after another, for each loop iteration. That way, the main loop can update its own variable, signal the first thread (using pthread_cond_signal) and then signal the second thread. It is important to note that we are trying to co-ordianate 3 threads, one of them being the main thread.

Comment: But @Manoj will loop will wait after sending condition signal. I can wait using mutex.. But is loop will wait till i lock the thread? and when i am printing final result in the code. i need to add more calculation using x1 and x2... hence needs to wait both thread there.. will it be helpful?

Comment: I have quickly coded your example to coordinate between the main thread and the two threads. I have also updated the answer above. The key thing is that instead of waiting on the while loop, now the wait has shifted to the pthread_cond_wait(). This is just a sample example -- please modify it as per your application need.

Comment: Thanks i will try to edit.. and will use your suggestions.. @Manoj Pandey